# How to copy all files in directory recursively and unzip compressed files on fly

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, zip

I have a huge collection of standard/compressed files in a directory with many subdirectories.

Now, I need to copy this structured directory and all contents (files and subdirectories) in another disk and unzip all compressed files.

So, to save time I'd want to copy all files in directory recursively and unzip compressed files on fly.

How can I do this?

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus I'm a newbie in Unix, I tried to solve it with _find_ but I can't find a solution, it's too difficult for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this as 3 separate steps, using `$SOURCE` and `$DEST` as your source and destination directories.

1. Recreate the source directory structure in the destination directory

   `find $SOURCE -type d | sed -e "s~^$SOURCE~~" | xargs -r -I dir mkdir -p "$DEST"/"dir"`
2. Move all files that don't need to be decompressed

   `find $SOURCE -type f -not -name '*.gz' | sed -e "s~^$SOURCE/~~" | xargs -r -I file cp "$SOURCE"/"file" "$DEST"/"file"`
3. Decompress all compressed files into the destination directory

   `find $SOURCE -type f -name '*.gz' | sed -e "s~^$SOURCE~~" | sed -e "s~.gz$~~" | xargs -r -I file bash -c 'gzip -dc "'"$SOURCE"'"/"file".gz > "'"$DEST"'"/"file"'`

That said, as a word of advice I would recommend using `rsync -av` to copy all the files and then `find . -name '*.gz' -exec gunzip \{\} \;` in the destination directory to decompress the files. This is a far simpler approach with fewer potential pitfalls. (The three steps above worked for me on a small test directory with a limited number of files and relatively simply filenames; YMMV for a more complex use case.)

Answer (score 0):

`tar` sounds like the command you want.

`tar cf - <dir> | (cd <path-to-other-dir>; tar xf -)` is usually what I use when I want to copy the contents of a directory to another folder.